# how to rename file when zipping it?

Tags: linux, zip

I'm planning to pack some files into a zip file on my ubuntu OS. For example, I have files a, b and c. I want to put them into a new.zip file. But these files have to be renamed to a1, b1 and c1 in the zip file. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you rename the files before the zipping? If instead of `zip` you used `tar` you might consider [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/) for post processing some `tar` archive...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The original files a,b and c are still in use by other programs, so I can't rename them. I don't wanna use tar cos my clients who will download the zip file may not know or like the tar format.

Comment: You can rename or [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) a file which is opened by some other program. Don't forget that Unix files may have more than one name (with hard links, see the `ln` command)

Comment: You could rename files inside ZIP like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710341/linux-zip-command-add-a-file-with-different-name

Answer (score 1):

you can use zipnote. Use this command :

```
echo -e "@ myOldFileName.txt\n@=myNewFileName.txt" | zipnote -w myzip.zip
```